# Duda con CSS grid

Tags: html, css

[image: Layout de ejemplo]

Estoy aprendiendo sobre CSS grid y he querido intentar reproducir esta imagen maquetandolo con html y css nativos, pero no consigo realizar las pequeñas cajas debajo de la información principal

Alguna ayuda o página donde puedan explicar esto de manera que pueda entenderlo mejor.

[image: Esto es lo que tengo en mi style.css]
Esto es lo que tengo en mi style.css

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si, me refiero a como renderizar el texto de la información adicional que se ve debajo del precio con ese mismo orden a traves del css grid

Comment: Bienvenido a SO! Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender cómo preguntar. Por favor comparte tu código en forma de texto, no imagen, y el HTML para crear un [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y así poder ayudarte.

Comment: @DavidSosa checa [esto](https://codepen.io/jaimemenendez/pen/QWgPKBa) e intenta entenderlo

Comment: Muchas gracias!! no conocia el metodo de repeat y tambien estaba fallando en no poner más etiquetas. Sin duda una gra ayuda, a seguir empoyando

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar grid areas. Visita ese codepen: https://codepen.io/inkinvissible/pen/PoKJOQV